# Spring JPA / Hibernate is calling full update before a special update using @Modifying and @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring repository for the class Business:

```
public interface BusinessRepository extends JpaRepository<Business, String> {
```

That include a simple method to update just one field (updateDatetime):

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Business business set business.updateDatetime = :updateDatetime where business.businessKey = :businessKey")
int setUpdateDatetimeForBusiness(@Param("updateDatetime") String updateDatetime, @Param("businessKey") String businessKey);
```

The problem is when I call this method:

```
businessRepository.setUpdateDatetimeForBusiness(business.getUpdateDatetime(), business.getBusinessKey());
```

The logs shows the following:

```
Hibernate: update business set name=?, timezone=?, updatedatetime=? where business_id=?
Hibernate: update business set updatedatetime=? where business_id=?
```

The method is calling a full update for the entity, then calling my update. What should I change to call just the second update?

Comment: Could you post the code that calls the method?

Comment: Updates made to a persistent entity within a transaction will be automatically flushed when the transaction ends. So I would guess that you have loaded and modified (set the updateDateTime) a persistent entity within a transaction. When your transactional method returns the entity manager flushes the changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Query(value="update something", nativeQuery=true)
```

`nativeQuery=true` try to add this

---

**update**

Sorry for didn't read the question carefully.

As the inflammation you provided, I can't find the problem out. But I do have
 suggestions for you.

The entity managed by `EntityManager` can automatically persist into database, and you log `Hibernate: update business set name=?, timezone=?, updatedatetime=? where business_id=?` seems like it updated all the fields? If so, the update much more likely called by `EntityManager`.

And you can change the `flushMode` to `COMMIT` to see if this make changes. (just for testing if the problem is caused by `EntityManager`'s automatically update)
  eg: `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=COMMIT` in spring boot.

---

My test code:

service:

```
import cn.eeemt.dao.TagRepository;
import cn.eeemt.entity.Tag;
import cn.eeemt.service.TagService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class TagServiceImpl implements TagService {

    @Resource
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Override
    public void update(String newDescription) {
        Tag tag = step1(newDescription);
        step2(tag.getDescription(), tag.getId());
    }

    @Transactional
    public Tag step1(String newDescription) {
        Optional<Tag> byId = tagRepository.findById(1);
        Tag tag = byId.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
        System.out.println(tag);
        tag.setDescription(newDescription);
        // tagRepository.save(byId.get());  // I did not update it!!!
        return tag;
    }

    private void step2(String description, Integer id) {
        tagRepository.updateSome(description, id);
    }
}
```

repository:

```
import cn.eeemt.entity.Tag;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Tag tag set tag.description = :description where tag.id = :id")
    void updateSome(@Param("description") String description, @Param("id") int id);
}
```

**when `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=ALWAYS`**

log looks like:

> Tag{id=1, name='ffadsfasd', description='dasfadsg', articles=[]}
>   Hibernate: update tag set description=?, name=? where id=?
>   Hibernate: update tag set description=? where id=?

**when `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=COMMIT`**

log looks like:

> Tag{id=1, name='ffadsfasd', description='dasfadsgaaer', articles=[]}
>   Hibernate: update tag set description=? where id=?

---

If the problem it what I said above, it's not good idea to change `flushMode` unless it's suitable for you situation. You'd better to refactor you code for better design.

---

information may help you:

- [Transactional saves without calling update method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190926/transactional-saves-without-calling-update-method)
- [Entity Lifecycle](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06.html)

Comment: What if the OP wants to use JPQL? How is this even related to the problem at hand?